# How to set maintenance mode for Laravel 5.8 behind load balancer in EC2 instance and access from my office?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I want to use Laravel maintenance mode on EC2 instance behind the load balancer because I do not want to touch AWS console for returning maintenance content.

Moreover, I want to access my app via web browser from my office while maintenance mode.

I did following and it turns into maintenance mode.

But, I can not see my app from my office although the IP at my office in the allow list.

`php artisan down --allow=127.0.0.1 --allow=myip/34`

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Here is my environment information-
PHP: 5.7
Laravel: 5.8

Also, I have following source code in App/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php

`class TrustProxies extends Middleware
    {
        protected $proxies = '*';
        protected $headers = [
            Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
            Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
            Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
            Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
            Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
        ];
    }`

Regards,

Comment: Ahm... why you think it's not working? Unfortunately I can not reproduce your whole setup, but what you did looks pretty reasonable to me

Comment: There exists an good [article](https://medium.com/@mattkingshott/multi-server-maintenance-mode-laravel-b9c2095e18b6) (from 2018) about such cases maybe it will help you.

Comment: @Nemoden Thanks for your comment. My question was unclear so I added more explanation. What I want to do is I want to access my app from my office while maintenance mode.

Comment: Which part of it isn't working exactly? Is the app not going into maintenance mode or are you not able to access it from your office?

Comment: @Rwd Thanks for your comment. My app is in maintenance mode, but, I am not able to see from office although the IP is in the allow list. I will add this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're behind a load balancer you'll be receiving the ip of that load balancer rather than the client ip.

**TL;DR**

In your `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` change the `protected $proxies;` line to be:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

---

Since Laravel 5.4, there is an out-of-the-box way of dealing with this: [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy). If you're using an earlier version of Laravel you can still use the package, however, you'll have to install it yourself.

Where possible, you should try and set the ip addresses of the reverse proxy, however, this isn't possible with AWS since the ip addresses of the load balancer change all the time (source: https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/wiki/IP-Addresses-of-Popular-Services#aws-elastic-load-balancers).

For more information, you can refer to the Laravel documentation [Configuring Trusted Proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) or the [Github page](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) for the underlying package.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will take a look at it :)

Comment: I added protected $proxies = '*';. but it dose not work at all....w

Comment: @LeoS That is strange, I tested it with an ec2 instance (aws eb) before posting the answer. Just to double check, when you put `--allow=myip/34` did you put an ip actual ip address in or just "myip"? I would suggest trying to debug this by creating a route that outputs the ip address to and seeing if it changes when you have `$proxies = '*';` in your `TrustProxies` middleware or not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I find my IP using this web site. https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and I put something like `--allow=0.0.0.0/34`. So, IP address should be okay. Also, I added `$proxies = '*';` as well.

Comment: I just recognized that we do not have following. Is that okay? `config/trustedproxy.php`

Comment: @LeoS The public IP won't necessarily be the IP you're application is getting because the IP will be for the load balancer which is why I suggested adding a route and outputting the IP there. Are you still having issues with the by the way or did the above answer help solve you're issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying your Middleware code there, it is better to put this into your configuration file. Add `config/trustedproxy.php` file with the following code in it:

```php
<?php

return [
    'proxies' => env('TRUSTED_PROXIES'),
];
```

Then add the following line to your `.env` file:

```
TRUSTED_PROXIES="*"
```

Also a side note: it is generally not really a good idea to trust all proxies, because people can just fake the `X-Forwarded-For` headers. Instead, you can put the IPs for your private IP subnet, whatever it is in your EC2 VPC. It would be one of the RFC 1918 private IP networks, by default it would be one of the `172.x.x.x` subnets.  You can then substitute the `"*"` in the code above with something like `"172.16.0.0/12"` or whatever your private subnet is — you can look it up in your VPC settings.